# Search query on multiple table join with multi level hierarchy relation (SQL or LINQ)

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, asp.net-core-webapi

**I've four model class like these**

```
    public class BlogUser
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName ="nvarchar(200)")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<BlogCommentLikeAndDislike> BlogCommentLikeAndDislikes { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public List<BlogComment> BlogComments { get; set; }
    }

    public class BlogPost
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long BlogUserId { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        [Required]
        public string Post { get; set; }
        public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
        public ICollection<BlogComment> BlogComments { get; set; }
        public BlogUser BlogUser { get; set; }
    }

    public class BlogComment
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long BlogPostId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }
        public long BlogUserId { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(300)]
        [Required]
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public BlogPost BlogPost { get; set; }
        public ICollection<BlogCommentLikeAndDislike> BlogCommentLikeAndDislikes { get; set; }
        public BlogUser BlogUser { get; set; }
    }

    public class BlogCommentLikeAndDislike
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long BlogCommentId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BlogUser")]
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        public bool IsLike { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public BlogComment BlogComment { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public BlogUser BlogUser { get; set; }
    }
```

**I've a table on client like this with *search field*.**

[image]

And these data come form a api here is the method

```
        public async Task<Object> GetReport(TableSearchOptions tableSearchOptions)
        {
            try
            {
                var data = await appDbContext.BlogPosts
                .Include(x => x.BlogUser)
                .Include(e => e.BlogComments)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.BlogUser)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.BlogCommentLikeAndDislikes)
                .Skip(tableSearchOptions.Skip != null? (int)tableSearchOptions.Skip: 0)
                .Take(tableSearchOptions.Take != null ? (int)tableSearchOptions.Take : 3)
                .ToListAsync();
                return data;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
            return null;
        }
```

Now what I want to do, I want to create a method like Search() and to create that method I need such a SQL or LINQ query to search this table data base on blog user name, Blog post, blog comment, blog post date, like or dislike field. In one word search by any field will return the result set. How do I achieve it.

Comment: Put a `Where` with liberal use of `||` and `Contains`. And then wonder why it takes 5 minutes to deliver a result :D

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just need to know the best practices that's why I asked this question. I know if someone help me to write the search query then I'll learn a lot of thing from that. Could you please help me for that?

Comment: Have a go at putting `.Where(...)` between the last include and the skip- we are here to help out if you get stuck. Start simple, just one clause on one column